# facebook Graph api fetch list of all friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I am working in a project where i have to integrate face-book graph-api. Everything is going well
 but i stuck in a problem to fetch my face book friend list using /me/friends/. It return me only 
 those friends which has log in with my app, but i want my all friend list

```
 $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken());
 $friends= (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/friends' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()
->asArray();
 echo '<pre>' . print_r( $friends, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

It return
     [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => Nitin Chamola
                    [id] => 792718557454395
                )

```
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Ajay Aggarwal
                [id] => 765446336856080
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Manjit Singh Jassal
                [id] => 1538019986415496
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [name] => Sapna Thakur
                [id] => 1518184435101741
            )

    )

[paging] => stdClass Object
    (
        [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/1587893521432407/friends?access_token=CAAGPXznoOFkBAOCKznoJ4AwZBi9DhlNQYuvgn1qT1Qz3x0JE5mUT5JXOnEnhPtpcriJjoRB5K2yNW3B2L0PtJEcgy8MK3NbZB2oHeBPEeayudFSSxDDOTYUc4J3Q9zDkBqsIGcDcHyzECBtHqOM2HKRUwdOmsSRAJQ41lVWj0T1O2bH1P4ZC2Or2Gv0FuVTL7Wp2xudgGsDHyjwLvGT&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=enc_AexVs_nuUmTOuF4B5iplPfzsuPs6vtQGx7TV_pH-cINIX2nUIvn3vdmWzNINrKx-vqDnpavxrIA_kr3aqSr6lw4k
    )

[summary] => stdClass Object
    (
        [total_count] => 242
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Graph API 2 and above you can no longer do this. You can only fetch the list of those friends who use your app i,e who have given permission to your app. This has been done by fb for security reasons.